# deleting database in oracle 10g query

Tags: oracle10g

i want to drop a database in oracle 10g..

i saw the command 
DROP database.

How to run this query and drop database.

If i tried this query, it is showing error as invalid query.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle [documentation states](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/create009.htm):

> Dropping a database involves removing
>   its datafiles, redo log files, control
>   files, and initialization parameter
>   files. The DROP DATABASE statement
>   deletes all control files and all
>   other database files listed in the
>   control file. To use the DROP DATABASE
>   statement successfully, all of the
>   following conditions must apply:
>
> ```
> The database must be mounted and closed.
>
> The database must be mounted exclusively--not in shared mode.
>
> The database must be mounted as RESTRICTED.
> ```
>
> An example of this statement is:
>
> ```
> DROP DATABASE;
> ```
>
> The DROP DATABASE statement has no
>   effect on archived log files, nor does
>   it have any effect on copies or
>   backups of the database. It is best to
>   use RMAN to delete such files. If the
>   database is on raw disks, the actual
>   raw disk special files are not
>   deleted.
>
> If you used the Database Configuration
>   Assistant to create your database, you
>   can use that tool to delete (drop)
>   your database and remove the files.

Comment: I just know how to drop database using admin role in oracle. For information related to c#.net please find the answer in the internet. If there is answer, please post here for other can learn.